# Redirect after POST using reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express, reactjs

I have express configured to route to `redirect` as follow:

in routes/redirect.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('received POST data: ' + req.body.data); 
});
module.exports = router;
```

in app.js:

```
...
var redirect = require('./routes/redirect');
var app = express();
...
app.use('/redirect', redirect);
```

and in component.jsx:

```
var React = require('react');
var Component = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
            return (
                <form>
                    <input type="text" ref="data" placeholder="Send some data"/>
                    <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Send</button>
                </form>
            );
        },

     handleSubmit: function() {
            var data = this.refs.data.getDOMNode().value;
            // TODO: how do I send 'data' as POST request and redirect to /redirect ?
            // i.e. POST and redirect to localhost:3000/redirect like in a classic 
            // form submit{action='redirect',method='post'} way 
        }
});

module.exports=Component;
```

I've included the description of my question in the TODO section of the code. Is there a way to do it purely with Node+React without installing all kind of plugins?

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `fetch` API which is supported in most modern browsers. See [MDN for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```
    var Component = React.createClass({
        render: function(){
                return (
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" ref="data" placeholder="Send some data"/>
                        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Send</button>
                    </form>
                );
            },

         handleSubmit: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var data = this.refs.data.getDOMNode().value;
                fetch("<url to where to post>", {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: 'data'
                }).then(this.handleRedirect)                    
            },

        handleRedirect: function(res){
            if( res.status === 200 ){
                // redirect here
                // window.location.href = 'http://localhost:300/redirect';
            }else {
              // Something went wrong here
            }

        }
    });


    module.exports=Component;
```

Hope it helps.